# Bash script doesnt run when passed as UserData to ec2 instance

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to execute a shell script that initiates a python script by passing a shell script as UserData to ec2 instance when its launched (python SDK).

The target python script I am trying to run, needs to be run as a user (not root) with all the user environment variables. The bash script that runs this target python script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc
source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
source /home/ubuntu/kartographer/install_isolated/setup.bash
source /home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
/home/ubuntu/takecontrolofEC2.py $1 $2
```

The bash script that I pass along with the ec2 creation is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Start processing the data" > /home/ubuntu/process.log
whoami >> /home/ubuntu/process.log
sudo -H -u ubuntu bash -c "/home/ubuntu/runpostprocessingscript.sh s3://mapping/unprocessed_data/tax/2016-02-11/ s3://processed-data/test/tax/ >> /home/ubuntu/process.log"
```

The o/p of process.log is

```
Start processing the data
root
```

I do not understand why my last command doesn't get executed. The same command works when I run it from the terminal as root. i.e.

```
sudo su
<last command>
```

I am quite not sure where I am going wrong. Anything helps.

Thanks

**FYI:** The python script takes long time (2-3 hrs) to finish processing the data.

**Note:** This works when I use SSH / paramiko. But my intention is to have the ec2 instance completely enclosed (without ssh interface) as the data needed is on s3.

Comment: Have you tried adding `set -x` to your `runpostprocessingscript.sh` script to see if you can get more debug output?

Comment: What information does `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` contain?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried it out again today and it seems to work. totally weird, but works. -Thanks